# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python

I have been having some problems creating a character printer for an assignment in school, and I do not know how to solve it despite looking everywhere on StackOverflow. I am trying to enable the user to enter the symbols they want for the first two top and bottom lines, and have their two texts centered with forward and backslashes based on word length. However, this has been proven to be a problem.

I have tried to change variables as well as create variables that encapsulate the length of the text into an integer, this has proven to be unsuccessful.

```py
Repeats = input("How many times should the symbol repeat (1-30 CHARACTERS)?:")
insertText = input("Please enter text:")
insertText = str(insertText)
insertMoreText =input("Please enter text (again):")
insertMoreText= str(insertMoreText)
Repeats = int(Repeats)

#Determining text lengths/stored variables:
text1length = len(insertText)
text2length = len(insertMoreText)
forwardSlash = str("/")
backSlash = str("\\")
symbolsbeforeText = "*"
if(Repeats <= 30):
    print(firstSymbol * Repeats)
    print(secondSymbol * Repeats)
    print(symbolsbeforeText * Repeats)
    print (forwardSlash * text1length) & (insertText.upper()) & (forwardSlash 
    * text1length)
    print (backSlash * text2length) + (insertMoreText.lower()) + (backSlash * 
    text2length)
    print(symbolsbeforeText * Repeats)
    print(secondSymbol * Repeats)
    print(firstSymbol * Repeats)    
else:
    print("You have reached the repetition threshold, please try again.")
```

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\colby\trainingTime.py", line 28, in <module>
 print (forwardSlash * text1length) & (insertText.upper()) & 
 (forwardSlash * text1length)
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Process terminated with an exit code of 1
```

Comment: what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf Hi! I am using the latest version of Python 3.7

Comment: I just added an answer to your question. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` function always returns `None`, and you're performing bitwise-and operation with the returning value of `print` and `(insertText.upper())`, which is a string, which causes the said error.

You should call `print` with the entire expression enclosed in parentheses as an argument instead:

```
print((forwardSlash * text1length) & (insertText.upper()) & (forwardSlash * text1length))
print((backSlash * text2length) + (insertMoreText.lower()) + (backSlash * text2length))
```

Comment: How could I go about centering this text with the slashes wrapped around it?

Comment: You can use the [`str.center`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) method: `print(insertText.upper().center(overall_width, '/'))`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I figured out the centering portion myself, but thank you for this minor fix! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in Python 3+, print is a function that returns `None`, so:

```py
print(forwardSlash * text1length)
```

returns `None`, and

```py
insertText.upper()
```

returns a `str`. Therefore, you cannot perform a bit-wise `&` operation on `None` and `str`.

A very good way to solve this is using an f-string which is a Python feature available since Python 3.6:

```py
print(f"{backSlash * text2length} {insertMoreText.lower()} {backSlash * text2length}")
```

This will make your code more readable. See that you don't need to concatenate strings using `+` which probably lead to your confusion.